# Possible to capture application freeze ups

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, freeze

I am experiencing random freeze ups with my application where the entire window will become unresponsive.  The GUI doesn't respond to any user interaction and the window can't even be moved.  Task manager shows resources are normal, my application throws no errors and the program does not appear as 'Not Responding'.

I have checked the Event veiwer, and can see the following reference each time it occurs:

```
The program DM_Agent.exe version 2.0.14.0 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Action Center control panel.
 Process ID: fcd0
 Start Time: 01d2a365091f8a3f
 Termination Time: 4294967295
 Application Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\ApplicationPath\DrakeMon Client Suite\DM_Agent\DM_Agent.exe
 Report Id: 81ff18e8-0f74-11e7-80c7-000c2931dfd6
 Faulting package full name: 
 Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with threading as my application uses a number of timers to scan folders, applications and system resources periodically.  However, my application can work for days without freezing or sometimes only minutes.

This problem also doesn't occur on my test system, only in production.  I have created everything `thread-safe` as far as I'm aware, but I'm not getting any errors thrown to suggest otherwise.  And the fact that it's executing the same code for days without freezing would suggest that if there was a problem, it should show up relatively quick.

Is there some way I can try and capture these freeze ups.  I have `try/catch`'s on pretty much everything to try and capture anything irregular.

Comment: Hi, try/catch won't stop thread starvation / locks.
Also, when debugging be sure to look at Parallel Stacks output window if you don't already know about it.  Good luck!

Comment: @Monza Yeah I gathered it wouldn't, but is there any possible way I can find what is causing the locks?  I can't even determine what module or piece of code it could be failing at.

Comment: I'd pause it in the debugger when it's frozen and see which of the stacks is at what point in code.  You might find two different stacks fighting for a thread-protected resource etc.

Comment: @Monza, the problem is that is never freezes on my development machine.  Only on both production environments so far.  I do call `Me.Invoke(Sub() )` on all my from control updates.  Do you think this could be causing it?  Should I be using `delegates` and `If Me.InvokeRequired then...` maybe?

Comment: You might have to scaffold log entries all over the place.  Also, if you build in Release mode but still generate debug symbols you can connect remote debugger to your prod machine and watch from afar!  I'm not a VB guy so I can't give you any specific suggestions about the Me.Invoke() call :(